# RecyclerView adapter inheritance: ViewHolder tightly coupled

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have two RecyclerView adapters with mostly similar code. The only thing different in either is the onClick implementation in the ViewHolder of each adapter.

To DRY my code, I'd like to create an abstract base adapter and then perform inheritance. The skeleton of the base adapter is thus:

```
public abstract class BaseRvAdapter extends 
        RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseRvAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    }
}
```

And the skeleton of one of the child classes that are to inherit from the above BaseRvAdapter:

```
public class ChildRvAdapter extends BaseRvAdapter {

    public static class ViewHolder extends BaseRvAdapter.ViewHolder 
            implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    }
}
```

So far, it's working. Meaning the UI is getting displayed as expected. The problem is nothing happens when I click on an adapter item. I quickly noticed that BaseRvAdapter is tied to the ViewHolder inside its own class (`BaseRvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseRvAdapter.ViewHolder>`), but ChildRvAdapter is in no way hooked up to its own ViewHolder.

How do I solve that?

Comment: what you want exactly?  on item click listener?

Comment: you should use just one adapter for this and make some logic for different scenarios and use a listener to implement your scenario according to your logic

Comment: And use a custom listener which suits you better instead of using a base adapter.